# Binding Image URIs via Image.SetBinding() not working properly

Tags: forms, image, xamarin, uri

I'm using the following code snippet to bind a image url to a image object (used as one element in a ViewCell object).

```
   ...
   Image Picture = new Image()
            {
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
            }; // ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("sImageUrl")))
            Picture.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "sImageUrl");

   ...
```

The images in the list, for which I'm using that cell view, are not loading always. I was not able to identify the exact reason for the problem, but I think the problem is the load-process (for loading the images from the url/internet)..

Maybe the problem could be solved by setting the url via new Uri(...) as described in the documentation

```
var webImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
webImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png"));
```

Now my question: is there a workaround for binding a uri object? e.g.

```
   ...
   Image Picture = new Image()
            {
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
            }; // ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("sImageUrl")))
            Picture.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("sImageUrl")));

   ...
```

I'm working with xamarin studio (version 6.1.2, build 44, update channel "beta", os x).

Would be great if someone got a tipp.

Thanks a lot,

Alex

Comment: Why ImageSource.FromUri doesn't work for you as described in the documentation?

Comment: Hi, as soon as I'm trying to Bind the "uri" value I get the message:  Error CS1929: Type `Xamarin.Forms.Image' does not contain a member `SetBinding' and the best extension method overload `Xamarin.Forms.TemplateExtensions.SetBinding(this Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty, string)' requires an instance of type `Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate' (CS1929)

Answer (score 0):

after some more trying I found a solution.. I'm not sure if it's a secure / professional way.. But for now, it seems to work.

What I did: I implemented my own class "AsyncSrcImage", derived it from Image and added another bindable property:

```
public class AsyncSrcImage : Image
        {
            private static String sDefaultURL = "";

            public static readonly BindableProperty AsyncImgUrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AsyncImgUrl), typeof(String), typeof(AsyncSrcImage), sDefaultURL);
            public String AsyncImgUrl
            {
                get { return (String)GetValue(AsyncImgUrlProperty); }
                set { SetValue(AsyncImgUrlProperty, value); }
            }

        }
```

Additionally I adjusted the rendering process with a custom renderer. There I'm loading the image source via new Uri(...) as described in the documentation:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AsyncSrcImage), typeof(AsyncSrcImageRenderer))]

    public class AsyncSrcImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            AsyncSrcImage oImage = (AsyncSrcImage)Element;

            if (oImage != null && oImage.AsyncImgUrl != "")
            {

                oImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(oImage.AsyncImgUrl));

            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe that helps other folks ;)